# asp.net c# customer control on content page child of master page

Tags: c#, asp.net, eventhandler

My application was working before converting it to an asp.net Master/Content page architecture.  There is a custom control that has 3 buttons in one DIV and a chart in another DIV.  The custom control is added to the content page many times with a different chart in each. The same event handler services a button, regardless of how many times it appears on the screen.

After converting to a Master/Content page architecture, the event handler no longer receives the onClick event.

**The Content Page looks like this...**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm7.aspx.cs" Inherits="OperationalStats.Forms.WebForm7" %>
<%@ Register src="../Classes/UserControls/ChartWidget.ascx" tagname="ChartWidget" tagprefix="uc1" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
```

**And the user control page looks like this**

```
<%@ Control Language="C#"  AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="ChartWidget.ascx.cs" Inherits="OperationalStats.Classes.UserControls.ChartWidget" %>

<div id="TestDiv" class="floating-box" runat="server" style="border: medium solid #00FF00;  height: 270px; width: 250px">
    <div id="MenuDiv" runat="server">
        <asp:Button ID="FilterButton" runat="server" Text="Filter" class="btn btn-info btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" OnClick="FilterButton_Click" CommandName="Tests Delivered By Test Center" />
        <asp:Button ID="ZoomButton" runat="server" class="btn btn-info btn-sm" Text="Zoom" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" Width="50px" OnClick="ZoomButton_Click" />
        <asp:Button ID="ShowTableButton" runat="server" class="btn btn-info btn-sm" Text="Table" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" Width="50px" OnClick="TableButton_Click" />
    </div>
    <div id="ChartDiv" runat="server" style="position: relative; top: 6px; left: 2px; ">
    </div>
</div>
```

**The content declaration in the Master page looks like this**

```
<div class="container body-content">
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server">
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
<hr />
</div>
```

**The following is an example of a button's event handler**

```
namespace MyApp.Classes.UserControls
{
    public partial class ChartWidget : System.Web.UI.UserControl
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void FilterButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ...
        }
```

As I say, the event handler never receives the click event after converting to a Master/Content page architecture.

**Thoughts?**

Comment: Sorry.  The content page looks like this.......... <%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm7.aspx.cs" Inherits="OperationalStats.Forms.WebForm7" %>

<%@ Register src="../Classes/UserControls/ChartWidget.ascx" tagname="ChartWidget" tagprefix="uc1" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

</asp:Content>

Comment: You should never put lengthy code in comments. Instead, please update your code in the original question as needed.

Comment: update question no need to put code in command

Comment: I could figure out how to edit the original post.

Comment: As I dont see any controls on the page. Do you load the controls dynamically?

Comment: Yes.  The controls are added dynamically.